# Optimizing MySQL or table design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm puzzled with my SQL homework. I'm not an expert in databases. I'm using MySQL.

I have a table named 'news'

```
create table news
    title text not null,
    time DATE,
    ip varchar(15),
    reporter varchar(25),
    tag varchar(20),
    id int not null auto_increment,
    primary key(id)
)engine=innodb;
```

And I have a txt file 'news2.txt' with 1000000 lines of data.

I want to optimize my sql for speed.

Here is my SQL statement

```
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;

load data local infile "e:/news2.txt" into table news fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (title,time,ip,reporter,tag); 

SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
```

the 'news2.txt' contains like***'*Vivamus dictum ultrices Curae aliquet vel nunc Aenean,2013/10/8,10.0.0.252,Reed Wyatt,Science*'*** it's a row.

The execution time is 29.188s. Are there any problems with my table design? What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: You're just loading the data...?  I wouldn't be too concerned with speed... it is what it is.  Queries can be optimized but I'm not sure you can do much with this part of the process.  Are you looking for a tool to use or to automate it somehow..?

Comment: Import duration of `29sec` for that large amount of data is not a concern as you would not be repeating this every second . However importing into table of `MyISAM` storage engine might be faster than importing into table of `InnoDB` storage engine . Before running the import you could change it to `MyISAM` and after the import change back to `InnoDB` .

Comment: Alright,hum..I'm just wondering if there is a way to improve the loading speed...I didn't realize 29 second is an acceptable result.Thank you all guys.By the way,I have another 'user.txt' with{user_name,tag,user_id} three attributes...Is my design reasonable?Just for tables.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Data load

One million entries take some time to write to disk. Check the size of the table and imagine that it's not just copying a file it's doing some computations in order to save it as a DB record.

It's not something to be concerned about unless the homework clearly stats that speed is of the essence (which I doubt it would).

In a normal application inserting one million entries into the news table in 26s is exceedingly good performance... not to mention "where did the find all of those news articles"? In real life the application layer will most likely slow things down.

### Transactions

You could remove the "autocommit=0" from there (if you don't need it), because that means the entire load operation is being run transactionally which means the DB engine needs to write everything in a temporary place and check if every insert (of the one million you have) was successful before committing the data.

Running with "autocommit=1" would let the DB engine handle each insert as a transaction.

Usually one transaction per statement creates some degree of "transactional" overhead, and it's a good practice to run batches of transactions (50-100 statements per transaction) to minimize that overhead, but in the case of very large transactions the overhead builds up and cannot be held in memory so it needs to be written to disk which makes things work slower -- in this case it's better to use one transaction per statement (which can be run from memory) rather than one transaction per entire batch.

Comment: I'm not sure how to improve the speed.. and I saw some articles saying  set 'autocommit=0' may help,so I just tried..But it didn't make it better... time consumption still around 29s...Now I see...How would you design tables(could be two or more) with my 'news.txt' and 'user.txt' ? Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Table is very simple so the design is ok. Only I think you would want to add some indexes to speedup queries made against the table.

But there is a potential [security issue with LOAD DATA LOCAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html) depending on your workflow.